# form laravel and vueJS

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

i´m trying create a form with vueJS and laravel. Now i can create my form with a component vue, but my problem is that, i don´t know how i can pass my information returned for a query in controller to a component vue.

In blade with {{$user}} i can, but in vueJS i don´t know how.

too i have a problem with property in console.

thanks so much for help me

**In console**

```
    [Vue warn]: Property or method "direccion" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in
```

**component vueJS**

```
<form>
            <input type="hidden" v-model="token">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="email">Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" v-model="nombreUsuario" class="form-control" >
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" v-model="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" v-model="password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="direccion">Direccion</label>
                    <textarea v-model="direccion" class="md-textarea form-control" rows="3">
                        
                    </textarea>
                    <input type="hidden" v-model="id">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- EMPEZAMOS LA FUNCIONALIDAD CON VUE DE ESTA MANERA LE DAMOS FUNCIONALIDAD AL BOTON-->
            <button class="btn btn-primary mt-5" type="submit">Actualizar</button>
        </form>

</template>

<script>
    export default{
        mounted(){
            console.log('component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');


Vue.component('usuarios-component', require('./components/usuariosComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('formularioactualizacion', require('./components/datosUsuarios.vue').default);


// inicio de VUE

    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#contenedorVue',
        //components: {usuario},
        data:{
                id: '',
                nombreUsuario: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
                direccion: '',
                token: '',
                arrayTasks:[],
            },
            methods: {
                enviar(){
                    let url = '/actualizarDatos';
                    axios.post(url, {
                        id: this.id,
                        nombreUsuario: this.nombreUsuario,
                        email: this.email,
                        password: this.password,
                        direccion: this.direccion,
                        _token: this.token,
                    }).then(function(response){
                        this.arrayTasks = response.data;
                        console.log("aquí"+response);
                    }).catch(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    })
                }
            }
        });
```

**homeController**

```
 public function datosPersonales($cod_usuario){
    $usuario = \Auth::user();
    
return view('datosPersonales')->with("usuario", $usuario);
}
```

**MODIFY**

i changed my code.

**Routes**

```
// ruta para obtener los datos del usuario que está en la sesion
Route::get('/datosPersonales', function(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    return response()->json($user);
});

//ruta para cargar la vista
Route::get('/datosPersonalesView', 'HomeController@datosPersonales')->name('datosPersonales');
```

**EDIT**

**VIEW**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

    @include('layouts.sidebar')

    <!-- SE ESTABLECE V-MODEL para usarlo con vue, es como el ID -->
    <div id="contenedorVue" class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">


        <!-- este formulario se crea desde VUEJS -->
        <formularioactualizacion :id="id" :nombreUsuario="nombreUsuario"></formularioactualizacion>
    </div>
@endsection
```

***file.vue***

```
<

template>
            
        <pre>
            {{id}}
            {{nombreUsuario}}
        </pre>


</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props: ['id', 'nombreUsuario']
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can pass values to components via props. Here's the documentation. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `[Vue Warn]`

```js
// data:{} should be 

data(){ 
    return { 
        // your data object here 
    }
```

For an AJAX response from Laravel you need to create a route which returns a JSON response.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#creating-responses

Example:

```php
Route::get('/tasks', function () {
    $user = Auth::user();
    return response()->json($user);
});
```

To pass that data into a component you will need to use `props`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Example Prop

To set a prop, add the `user` variable like so.

```html
<my-component :user="user" />
```

Component

```js
<template>
    <pre>{{ user }}</pre>
</template>

export default {
    props: ['user'] // Define the prop here, which is now reactive
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how i can return response with a route that returned a view¿?? i need to create another route¿?

Comment: You need to create another route if you want to keep the current route as it is, if the page is just for AJAX requests then you don't need to return a `view`

Comment: ok, but sorry i don´t understand very well, because in my route actually, i´m doing a query for ger data user... If i use your response i don´t know how i can get the user data

Comment: I've added the user to the response. It will return the user's information.

Comment: thank you very much, but if i want returned too the view¿??

Comment: Add your endpoint for the `ajax` stuff to `routes/api.php` this will give them a route of `/api/tasks` and then leave you free to use `/tasks` for a view

Comment: i change my code, my routes, as you told me, but sorry i don´t know how i can continue. When i did the new route i can see my object JSON, but i don´t know as send the data to vue component

Comment: Ill add an example of props to my answer

Comment: if you can add a example I'd be really grateful

Comment: I've added one. The HTML and the Component code is above. You're basically using v-bind:PROP="DATA" and then telling the component which props to look for i.e. `props: ['user']`

Comment: thanks so much for help, i start to understand how works vue... but with this example, i´m trying show more than one props, but only show one. edit my question

Comment: It's because of the way you've named the prop. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case - `:nombreUsuario="nombreUsuario"` should be `:nombre-usuario="nombreUsuario"` - Same with components, the names are converted from `camelCase` to `kebab-case`

Comment: thank so much for your response and your time. All my changes are statics, i want to say that in app.js i put the value. but if i want load to database¿???

Comment: You would make another AJAX request to a different controller that would handle the database updating side of your app. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input has some good documentation - It would be the same process as your Controller function that returns the User. But it would look like something in that documentation